# web application login on behalf of another user

Tags: grails, single-sign-on

I need to enable a logged in user of a web application to perform some functionality on behalf of another user.

For example, lets say I logged in as an restaurant owner and I want to do some of the restaurant manager's work.

I should be able to get the landing page of the restaurant manager while logged inas restaurant owner. The application is built using grails and it will be a great help if you all can share your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement your authentication and user management using the standard spring-security-core plugin then that provides a ["switch user" function](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/15%20Switch%20User.html) that handles exactly this situation.

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
Logged in as <sec:username/>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>

<sec:ifSwitched>
<a href='${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_exit_user'>
   Resume as <sec:switchedUserOriginalUsername/>
</a>
</sec:ifSwitched>

<sec:ifNotSwitched>
   <sec:ifAllGranted roles='ROLE_SWITCH_USER'>

   <form action='${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_switch_user' method='POST'>
      Switch to user: <input type='text' name='j_username'/><br/>
      <input type='submit' value='Switch'/>
   </form>

   </sec:ifAllGranted>
</sec:ifNotSwitched>
```

Comment: Thank you Ian for your answer. will do an experiment and update.